# php, Mysql query to create a dropdown menu

Tags: php, mysql, menu, drop-down-menu

I just want to populate a multilevel dropdown menu which uses mysql and php using single table

sample menu url: 
http://www.vidiyarkarai.com/

(sorry for this i tried to include an image but i'm not allowed to upload images, please see the menu using above address, please never mind the language in that site...)

i just want to generate this type of menu using a single table, i did this using multiple tables which is not effective and slow in some cases, so i want to do it in a single table.

```
  /*menu should be like 

  - menu_name(show if parent_id=0) // parent id is 1 for this id --- level1
    -> menu_name(show if parent_id=1) // parent id is 2 for this id  --- level2
        ->-> menu_name(show if parent_id=2) // parent id is 3 for this id  --- level3
   */
            --
            -- Table structure for table `tm_menu`
            --

            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tm_menu` (
              `menu_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
              `menu_name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
              `menu_desc` text,
              `menu_link` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
              `item_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
              `item_pos` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
              `parent_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
              `created_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
              `updated_by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
              `created_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
              `ip` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
              `status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
              PRIMARY KEY (`menu_id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

            --
            -- Dumping data for table `tm_menu`
            --
```

FYU i include the sample data, please never mind about the language included with it

```
    INSERT INTO `tm_menu` (`menu_id`, `menu_name`, `menu_desc`, `menu_link`, `item_id`, `item_pos`, `parent_id`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `created_on`, `updated_on`, `ip`, `status`) VALUES
    (1, 'à®®à¯à®•à®ªà¯à®ªà¯', NULL, '', 1, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (2, 'à®¨à®®à®¤à¯ à®µà®°à®²à®¾à®±à¯', 'à®ªà®´à®¨à¯à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®°à¯ à®µà®°à®²à®¾à®±à¯ à®®à¯à®¤à®²à¯ à®¤à®±à¯à®•à®¾à®²à®¤à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®°à¯ à®µà®°à¯ˆ à®…à®±à®¿à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®•à¯Šà®³à¯à®µà¯‹à®®à¯', 'set3cd15f8f2940aff879df34df4e5c2cd1', 2, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (3, 'à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®•à®³à¯', 'à®ªà®©à¯à®©à¯†à®Ÿà¯à®™à¯à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯ à®¤à¯Šà®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà¯ à®‡à®ªà¯à®ªà¯‹à®¤à¯ à®µà®°à¯ˆà®¯à®¿à®²à¯à®®à¯, à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯‹à®Ÿà¯ à®•à®²à®¨à¯à®¤ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®•à®³à¯ à®®à®±à¯à®±à¯à®®à¯ à®¤à®±à¯à®ªà¯‹à®¤à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®•à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ à®ªà¯‡à®šà®ªà¯à®ªà®Ÿà¯à®®à¯ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®•à®³à¯, à®®à®±à¯à®±à¯à®®à¯ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿ à®µà®´à®•à¯à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿à®¯ à®¤à®•à®µà®²à¯ à®•à®³à®žà¯à®šà®¿à®¯à®®à¯', 'setf3e334d42863e8250c7d03efefbfd387', 3, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (4, 'à®®à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®•à®²à¯ à®¤à¯‹à®©à¯à®±à®¿ à®®à®£à¯ à®¤à¯‹à®©à¯à®±à®¾ à®•à®¾à®²à®¤à¯à®¤à¯‡ à®¤à¯‹à®©à¯à®±à®¿à®¯ à®¨à®®à¯ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®¯à®¿à®©à¯ à®®à®¾à®¨à¯à®¤à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯, à®ªà®°à®µà®¿ à®µà®¾à®´à¯à®®à¯ à®®à¯à®±à¯ˆ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿à®¯ à®¤à®•à®µà®²à¯ à®¤à®¿à®°à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà¯', 'set12a032ce9179c32a6c7ab397b9d871fa', 4, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (5, 'à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®ªà¯†à®°à¯à®žà¯à®šà¯‹à®±à¯à®±à¯à®¤à®¿à®¯à®©à¯ à®šà¯‡à®°à®²à®¾à®¤à®©à¯ à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯ à®¤à¯Šà®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®¿à®©à¯ à®µà®´à®¿à®¯à®¾à®• à®•à¯‹à®²à¯‹à®šà¯à®šà®¿à®¯ à®®à®¾à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿à®¯ à®µà®°à®²à®¾à®±à¯', 'set75c2af9d944a14ccbf79b39bf9c3a338', 5, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (6, 'à®•à®²à¯ˆà®•à®³à¯', 'à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®°à¯ à®µà®´à®¿ à®µà®¨à¯à®¤ à®†à®¯ à®•à®²à¯ˆà®•à®³à¯ à®…à®±à¯à®ªà®¤à¯à®¤à¯ à®¨à®¾à®©à¯à®•à¯à®®à¯ (à¯¬à¯ª), à®…à®¤à®©à¯ˆà®•à¯ à®•à®°à¯ˆà®•à®£à¯à®Ÿ à®®à®©à®¿à®¤à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯à®®à¯', 'set96930e61e073920d9327ad9b3ab58071', 6, '0', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (7, 'à®®à¯à®¤à®±à¯à®šà®™à¯à®• à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯', NULL, 'setb9aafae93ae640481cd3c38350f7ed99', 7, '0', 11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (8, 'à®‡à®Ÿà¯ˆà®šà¯à®šà®™à¯à®• à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯', NULL, 'set6afa2460019e37b04f04ff903df462d1', NULL, '2', 11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (10, 'Menu', NULL, 'dd', NULL, '8', 8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (9, 'à®•à®Ÿà¯ˆà®šà¯ à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯', NULL, 'set529e895d6ea5dee9ce1c5bef7012e9a1', NULL, NULL, 11, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (11, 'à®šà®™à¯à®• à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯', 'à®šà®™à¯à®• à®•à®¾à®²à®®à¯ à®Žà®©à¯à®ªà®¤à¯ à®•à®¿.à®®à¯. 2à®®à¯ à®¨à¯‚à®±à¯à®±à®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®²à®¿à®°à¯à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®•à®¿.à®ªà®¿. 2à®®à¯ à®¨à¯‚à®±à¯à®±à®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà¯ à®µà®°à¯ˆ. à®‡à®¨à¯à®¤à®•à¯ à®•à®¾à®² à®•à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ à®†à®Ÿà¯à®šà®¿ à®šà¯†à®¯à¯à®¤ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ˆà®ªà¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿ à®®à®¿à®•à®•à¯ à®•à¯à®±à¯ˆà®µà®¾à®© à®¤à®•à®µà®²à¯à®•à®³à¯‡ à®•à®¿à®Ÿà¯ˆà®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®³à¯à®³à®©.', 'setcbfcdf6865b58d28c232b6a5ec27b550', NULL, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (12, 'à®šà¯‡à®°à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®®à¯à®±à¯à®•à®¾à®²à®šà¯ à®šà¯‡à®°à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ˆà®ªà¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿ à®®à®¿à®•à®µà¯à®®à¯ à®…à®°à®¿à®¤à®¾à®•à®µà¯‡ à®šà¯†à®¯à¯à®¤à®¿à®•à®³à¯ à®‰à®³à¯à®³à®©, à®†à®©à®¾à®²à¯ à®šà®™à¯à®• à®•à®¾à®²à®šà¯ à®šà¯‡à®°à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ˆà®ªà¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿ à®šà®¿à®±à®¿à®¤à®³à®µà¯ à®šà¯†à®¯à¯à®¤à®¿à®•à®³à¯ à®‰à®³à¯à®³à®©', 'set63252149fe05360f32cb3e9c4385e932', NULL, '1', 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (14, 'à®ªà®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®‡à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®šà®®à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®°à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ à®®à¯‚à®´à¯à®•à®¿à®µà®¿à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà®¤à¯†à®©à®•à¯ à®•à®°à¯à®¤à®ªà¯à®ªà®Ÿà¯à®®à¯ à®•à¯à®®à®°à®¿à®•à¯à®•à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ 72 à®¨à®¾à®Ÿà¯à®•à®³à¯à®®à¯ à®¤à®²à¯ˆà®¨à®•à®°à®¾à®• à®¤à¯†à®©à¯à®®à®¤à¯à®°à¯ˆà®¯à¯à®®à¯ à®µà®¿à®³à®™à¯à®•à®¿à®¯à®¤à¯. à®ªà®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯ à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à®¿à®©à¯ à®¤à®²à¯ˆà®¨à®•à®°à®¾à®• à®µà®¿à®³à®™à¯à®•à®¿à®¯ à®‡à®¤à¯à®¤à¯†à®©à¯à®®à®¤à¯à®°à¯ˆ à®•à®Ÿà®±à¯à®•à¯‹à®³à®¿à®©à®¾à®²à¯ à®…à®´à®¿à®µà¯à®±à¯à®±à®¤à¯.à®‡à®•à¯à®•à®Ÿà®±à¯à®•à¯‹à®³à®¿à®²à¯ à®…à®´à®¿à®¯à®¾à®¤à¯ à®‡à®°à¯à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®Žà®žà¯à®šà®¿à®¯ à®¨à®¾à®Ÿà¯à®•à®³à®¿à®©à¯ à®¤à®²à¯ˆà®¨à®•à®°à®¾à®• à®•à®ªà®¾à®Ÿà®ªà¯à®°à®®à¯ à®µà®¿à®³à®™à¯à®•à®¿à®¯à®¤à¯.à®‡à®°à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¾à®®à¯ à®•à®Ÿà®±à¯à®•à¯‹à®³à®¾à®²à¯ à®…à®¨à¯à®¨à®¾à®Ÿà¯à®®à¯ à®…à®´à®¿à®µà¯à®±à¯à®±à®¤à¯.à®‡à®µà¯à®µà®´à®¿à®µà®¿à®©à¯ à®ªà®¿à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯ à®¤à®±à¯à®ªà¯‹à®¤à¯à®³à¯à®³ à®®à®¤à¯à®°à¯ˆ à®ªà®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯à®°à¯à®•à®³à®¿à®©à¯ à®¤à®²à¯ˆà®¨à®•à®°à®¾à®¯à®¿à®±à¯à®±à¯. à®ªà®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯ à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à®¾à®²à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯à®šà¯ à®šà®™à¯à®•à®®à¯ à®µà¯ˆà®¤à¯à®¤à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®µà®³à®°à¯à®•à¯à®•à®ªà¯à®ªà®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà®¤à¯.', 'set96442866e22d7aa54d31c360bac83c5e', NULL, '3', 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (15, 'à®ªà®²à¯à®²à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®¨à®¾à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà®¿à®²à¯ à®•à®¿.à®ªà®¿ à®¨à®¾à®©à¯à®•à®¾à®®à¯ à®¨à¯‚à®±à¯à®±à®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà¯ à®¤à¯Šà®Ÿà®•à¯à®•à®®à¯ à®®à¯à®¤à®²à¯ à®ªà®¤à¯à®¤à®¾à®®à¯ à®¨à¯‚à®±à¯à®±à®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®©à¯ à®¤à¯Šà®Ÿà®•à¯à®•à®®à¯ à®µà®°à¯ˆ à®à®±à®¤à¯à®¤à®¾à®´ 700 à®µà®°à¯à®Ÿà®™à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®†à®Ÿà¯à®šà®¿ à®ªà¯à®°à®¿à®¨à¯à®¤à®©à®°à¯. à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à®¤à¯ à®†à®Ÿà¯à®šà®¿ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®•à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®©à¯ à®µà®°à®²à®¾à®±à¯à®±à®¿à®²à¯ à®ªà®²à¯à®µà¯‡à®±à¯ à®…à®®à¯à®šà®™à¯à®•à®³à®¿à®²à¯ à®¤à®¿à®°à¯à®ªà¯à®ªà¯à®®à¯à®©à¯ˆà®¯à®¾à®• à®…à®®à¯ˆà®¨à¯à®¤à®¤à¯ à®Žà®©à®²à®¾à®®à¯. à®Žà®©à®¿à®©à¯à®®à¯ à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯à®Ÿà¯ˆà®¯ à®¤à¯‹à®±à¯à®±à®®à¯ à®ªà®±à¯à®±à®¿ à®¨à®®à¯à®ªà®¤à¯à®¤à®•à¯à®¨à¯à®¤ à®¤à®•à®µà®²à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®‡à®©à¯à®©à¯à®®à¯ à®•à®¿à®Ÿà¯ˆà®•à¯à®•à®µà®¿à®²à¯à®²à¯ˆ. à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯‡ à®Žà®© à®'à®°à¯ à®ªà®¿à®°à®¿à®µà®¿à®©à®°à¯ à®¨à®¿à®±à¯à®µ à®®à¯à®¯à®², à®µà¯‡à®±à¯ à®šà®¿à®²à®°à¯ à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯, à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®•à®¤à¯à®¤à¯à®•à¯à®•à¯ à®µà¯†à®³à®¿à®¯à®¿à®²à®¿à®°à¯à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®µà®¨à¯à®¤ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à®°à®²à¯à®²à®¾à®¤ à®‡à®©à®¤à¯à®¤à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®Žà®©à¯à®•à®¿à®©à¯à®±à®©à®°à¯. à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®®à¯‚à®²à®¤à¯à®¤à¯ˆà®¤à¯ à®¤à¯†à®©à¯à®©à®¿à®¨à¯à®¤à®¿à®¯à®¾à®µà®¿à®²à¯ à®®à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà¯à®®à®©à¯à®±à®¿à®ªà¯ à®ªà®¾à®°à®šà¯€à®•à®®à¯, à®ˆà®´à®®à¯ à®ªà¯‹à®©à¯à®± à®ªà®•à¯à®¤à®¿à®•à®³à®¿à®²à¯à®®à¯ à®†à®¯à¯à®µà®¾à®³à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®¤à¯‡à®Ÿà®¿à®¯à¯à®³à¯à®³à®¾à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯. à®®à¯à®±à¯à®•à®¾à®²à®ªà¯ à®ªà®²à¯à®²à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®µà¯†à®³à®¿à®¯à®¿à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿ à®šà®¾à®šà®©à®™à¯à®•à®³à®¿à®©à¯ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿ à®®à®±à¯à®±à¯à®®à¯ à®…à®µà®±à¯à®±à®¿à®©à¯ à®‰à®³à¯à®³à®Ÿà®•à¯à®•à®™à¯à®•à®³à¯ˆ à®µà¯ˆà®¤à¯à®¤à¯, à®‡à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®‡à®¨à¯à®¤à®¿à®¯à®¾à®µà®¿à®©à¯ à®µà®Ÿà®ªà®•à¯à®¤à®¿à®¯à®¿à®²à®¿à®°à¯à®¨à¯à®¤à¯ à®µà®¨à¯à®¤ à®'à®°à¯ à®ªà®¿à®°à®¾à®®à®£à®•à¯à®•à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯à®¿à®©à®°à¯ à®Žà®©à¯à®±à¯ à®šà®¿à®²à®°à¯ à®•à®°à¯à®¤à¯à®•à®¿à®±à®¾à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯. à®ªà®¿à®±à¯à®•à®¾à®²à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ à®…à®°à®šà®¿à®¯à®²à¯ à®¨à®¿à®²à¯ˆà®®à¯ˆà®•à®³à¯ˆà®•à¯ à®•à®°à¯à®¤à¯à®¤à®¿à®²à¯ à®•à¯Šà®£à¯à®Ÿà¯ à®ªà®²à¯à®²à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯ à®¤à®®à®¿à®´à¯ à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®¯à®¿à®©à¯ à®ªà®¯à®©à¯à®ªà®¾à®Ÿà¯à®Ÿà¯ˆ à®à®±à¯à®±à¯à®•à¯à®•à¯Šà®£à¯à®Ÿà®¤à®¾à®•à®¤à¯ à®¤à¯†à®°à®¿à®•à®¿à®±à®¤à¯.', 'set2883c92900dc63b1d8c69bb9824b7f96', NULL, '4', 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (16, 'à®®à®±à¯à®±à®µà®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'à®šà¯‡à®° à®šà¯‹à®´ à®ªà®¾à®£à¯à®Ÿà®¿à®¯ à®ªà®²à¯à®²à®µà®°à¯ à®…à®²à¯à®²à®¾à®¤ à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯, à®•à¯à®±à¯ à®¨à®¿à®² à®®à®©à¯à®©à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', 'set2015c864ee11b1299e6440d8a2bfacda', NULL, '5', 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (17, 'à®ªà®¿à®± à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿à®•à®³à¯', '', 'set6e3338a3f3b9f21f5086563b912eaee7', NULL, NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (18, 'à®®à¯Šà®´à®¿ à®µà®´à®•à¯à®•à¯à®•à®³à¯', '', 'set38de43659e6c6de074b139179b400b6c', NULL, NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1),
    (13, 'à®šà¯‹à®´à®°à¯à®•à®³à¯', '', '8cd76b2615a3c5f364cbbc0e78852efe', NULL, '2', 5, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I lost you over here `menu should be like`

Comment: what is the problem ... what have you tried?

Comment: Perhaps i should include an image which explains what i'm trying exactly, i'll include that in a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to store trees in databases effectively.

http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Answer (score 0):

I do this using a recursive function, something along the lines of:

```
function get_pages ($parent_id='') {
  if ($parent_id == '') {     // if first call to function there's no parent id
    $pages = list of pages from db //use your own code here to pull all cats with no parent
  }
  else {
    $pages = list of pages with $parent_id as their parent_id
  }

  echo "<ul>";  //open list
  foreach ($result as $page) {
    echo "<li><a href=' << path to this page >> '></li>";
    $query = code to check for pages with this page as their parent
    if (query returns a result - ie there are sub pages) {
      get_pages($page['id']);  // this is the key, the function calls itself passing the current page as the parent so it only gets the sub pages
    }
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Nested Sets data structure for tree-like menus. It will save lots of sql queries.

See the discussion about Nested Sets here: [Searching for the best PHP nested sets class (PEAR class excluded)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272010/searching-for-the-best-php-nested-sets-class-pear-class-excluded)